# No notification (+15) for accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

Yesterday my answer was accepted, but I got no notification in top bar, moreover, top bar still shows that I earned 45 reps

[image]

while reputation tab shows right 60 rep.

[image]

## Update: July, 11

Again having this problem:

In the dropdown:

[image: dropdown: +23]

In the rep tab:

[image: rep tab: +19]

You see, first down votes in the drop down are missing.

Comment: That's because of the -485 from the bounty. Until there is positive change, you won't see any rep notification unless you click the icon thus "resetting" the counter.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I clicked yesterday. And, don't you see, it shows **45** reps instead of **60**.

Comment: You clicked it after setting the bounty and before having the answer accepted?

Comment: Followup question: you see rep change notifications now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting thing: today morning I saw rep notification for my answer on MSE (+10), but didn't see notification on my answer on SO. (I saw notification of up vote, but didn't see notification of accept) Yes, now I see notifications.

Comment: So maybe temporary hiccup, I'd say no-repro anyway. :/

Comment: Cool, looks like your flag was the 6th, that spam post is finally nuked. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue at this time. If you see it again please let us know!

Comment: It didn't happen to me since June 8, but ironically happened to me today :D I'll post images, ok?

Comment: @nicael sure thing, any images appreciated!

Comment: Wait, you renamed yourself? ;-)

Comment: Added new images.